# How to run a session without updating parameters in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I know how to use Tensorboard to get the graph, however just curious if I could get testing loss value during training process by leaving out "train_op". Also, I'm wondering if it's ok to get any value of other dataset without training them simply by deleting "train_op".

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y), name='square_mean')
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# this is for training, and I put train_op inside.
for _ in xrange(step):
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_:np.transpose([batch_y])})

    # just feed the data and get one loss value in some epochs
    loss_test = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: testing_batch, y_: np.transpose([label_t_batch])})
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out the `train_op` is perfectly fine as it's a node (more or less) like all others. Leaving it out will just not run it - meaning that the gradient descent will not happen.

As for your second question, as long as the data format of the other datasets you're talking about fit the input format of your graph, there should not be any issue.